# Why is Win32_DiskPartition is not displaying all partitions?

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am writing a script in PowerShell to grab a list of disks and partitions. If you look at the screenshot, diskpart is saying there are four partitions, but WMI is only saying there are three. I thought WMI would be the definitive sources of information for Windows. Any thoughts, maybe is there a way for WMI to rescan or maybe a C# import to call instead.

I also cannot use `Get-Partition` because I need it to be backwards compatible with Powershell 2.0.

[image: Diskpart side-by-side Get-WmiObject]

Comment: It would appear the recovery partition is hiding from WMI.

Comment: Sometimes older tools such as DiskPart are just a better route to go. Some information that WMI has the ability to get isn't _all_ of the information you actually need and this is a good example of it.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 that appears the be the case here, but I have other instances where the last partition is the primary and that gets dropped, so it seems its dropping the last partition

Comment: @cet51 I wish I could use diskpart, however it does not tie in very well when programming a script

Comment: Use diskpart /s.  You absolutely can script it.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 thanks, I did not know that

Comment: After some digging, I'm now realizing its not dropping the last partition, but its dropping the "Reserved" (MSR) partition. Not sure why the partition # or indexes are not lining up. It also does not show up in Disk Management, https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/a0a64818-6150-40b4-b5b3-915eb8fe31c9/msr-reserved-partition-does-not-appear-in-disk-management-nor-in-my-backup-program?forum=w8itproinstall